# setting height of divs to window height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have four divs with different IDs. How would I set height for all these divs?

```
<div id="slide-1">a</div>
<div id="slide-2">b</div>
<div id="slide-3">c</div>
<div id="slide-4">d</div>
```

I know we can do something like this below, but there are other divs too before this.

```
$('div').height($(window).height());
```

I want to set these four divs to window height alone. I can't hard-code here as the slides may vary.

Comment: instead of `$('div').height($(window).height());` put the div id `$('#slide-1').height($(window).height());` for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this will select all the divs that their ids start with "slide-" and set the height to window height:

```
$('div[id^="slide-"]').height($(window).height());
```

Comment: And fiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/f3C3V/. Also please replace `$(window).height` with `$(window).height()` to make answer correct

Answer (score 2):

```
$('div[id^="slide-"]').css("height", $(window).height() + 'px');
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/463KU/1/

Comment: It will set height for all DIVs on page. OP talked about only selected 4 DIVs

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6hbkj/)

```
    $('div').filter(function() { return /^slide-[1-4]$/.test( this.id ); })
    .height( $(window).height() );
```

Answer (score 0):

if you like to increase the hieght of specific divs use class for multiple

```
<div class="divHeight" id="slide-1">a</div>
<div class="divHeight" id="slide-2">b</div>
<div class="divHeight" id="slide-3">c</div>
<div class="divHeight" id="slide-4">d</div>

$('.divHeight').height($(window).height());
```

Answer (score 0):

I also recommended you use this way to get window height:

```
var windowHeight = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;

<div class="divHeight" id="slide-1">a</div>
<div class="divHeight" id="slide-2">b</div>
<div class="divHeight" id="slide-3">c</div>
<div class="divHeight" id="slide-4">d</div>

$('.divHeight').height(windowHeight);
```